# How to generate accuracy from a saved model of Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I already trained my Keras model in .h5. My model use 6 classes and it able to classify all the classes by using images. The model able to output the name of the class that it successfully classified. However, I want to generate accuracy when testing the model with an image input by user. I already searching everywhere but still there are no answer for this problem.

```
model = load_model('prototype-tl2-80-20.h5')
classes = { 1:'Kacip Fatimah',
        2:'Mempisang',
        3:'Misai Adam',
        4:'Pandan Serapat',
        5:'Tapak Sulaiman',
        6:'Tongkat Ali'}

image = Image.open(file_path)
image = image.resize((224,224))
image = numpy.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
image = numpy.array(image)
pred = model.predict_classes([image])[0]    
sign = classes[pred+1]
print(sign)
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "generate accuracy"?

Comment: What I means is when user input an image into the system to classify the classes of the image, the system able to classify it but sometimes it showing wrong classification. For end user, they do not know whether the system giving a right classification or not since there are no information about it. To tackle this problem, I want to output the accuracy for the classification for each of the image but I still cannot find the solution.

Comment: Ah, what you are asking is called the confidence or probability, and it is just the output of your model, use model.predict and take the argmax manually,  and the max over the model output will give you the probability, but in any case that probability will not give you much information.

Comment: Thank you very much sir for the information. Great to know that I have a wrong understanding about the confidence.

Answer (score 0):

to predict an image using a trained model you have to be careful to make sure the image is processed exactly as the training images were processed. The image should be the same size (height,width) as the training images and have the same number of color bands example 'rgb' or 'grayscale'.  Make sure color bands are in the same  order as used in training. Next you must  apply the same preprocessing to the image. For example if your training images were scaled to be between 0 and 1 then you need to rescale your test image with image=image/255. After that than do

```
pred = model.predict(image) 
index=np.argmax(pred)
class=classes[index]
print (index, class)
```

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I already implemented your suggestion but I still do not know how to output the accuracy of the classification from an image input by user. This is important if we want to know whether the classification is true or not according to the rate of accuracy.